# Not empty LiteSQL DB at start

Tags: android, sqlite

I think that this is rather easy question. I am too young in android stuff already. I want to prepare application which will be using database. In every example I've shown, there is an empty database where application is firstly started and after that there are some inserts. I want to have app with rather big db so I want to have filled db when app is started. How can I prepare db and attach it to program?

Comment: please search before asking!! you must prepare a script in the assets folder! please search '-1'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. put your filled database in Package's Asset directory,
2. at application runtime just copy that database to application's internal storage like
   `data/data/<package name>/database` directory.
3. then use it.

EDIT: this for copy database from asset directory to database directory,

```
private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {

        try {
            // Open your local db as the input stream
            InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open("your Database file name");

            // Path to the just created empty db
            String outFileName = "/data/data/<package name>/databases/";
            OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

            // transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }

            // Close the streams
            myOutput.flush();
            myOutput.close();
            myInput.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {

            Log.e("error", e.toString());

        }

    }
```