# When I export Android apk file, SQLite data not included

Tags: android, sqlite

After exporting Android apk file, there is no data included in SQLite database (I mean, empty database only attached).

Comment: Elaborate your question. What you have done for including SQLite database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following stackoverflow post may answer your question:

[Updating prepopulated database in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4189956/updating-prepopulated-database-in-android)

In addition the following blog entry (based on the above answer may be useful):

http://blog.luxteam.net/2011/01/04/prefilled-database-in-android-application/

Search goggle for "Prefilled Database Android" may also get you some relevant results

Answer (score 2):

put your `filled database` in `asset directory` and `programatically copy` that database in

`data/data/<package name>/database` directory when your application runs.

EDIT :

look at this my answer,

[Not empty LiteSQL DB at start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7496229/not-empty-litesql-db-at-start/7496308#7496308).

Comment: seems great. Hope it will be helpful.