# SQLite Database Can't Be Accessed From Android Phone

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, mobile

I want to ask about my SQLite database on Android Studio. I have a database and stored in this path: **/data/data/com.example.ilhamakbar.yukmasakbygd/databases/**.

When I opened it from Nox App Player, the database works and shows any tables and all data that I already inserted. However, when I build my APK and run it from my phone (*Android 6.0.1 Marshmallow*), it says that there were no data in my database.

***For example when I clicked button View on TabActivityAdministrator.java, the database will be shown in Nox App player, but won't be shown in my mobile phone.***

I already follow some instrunctions from these links below, but it seems doesn't work.

> 1. [Simple export and import of a SQLite database on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6540906/simple-export-and-import-of-a-sqlite-database-on-android)
> 2. [Import and Use External Database in Android](http://www.javahelps.com/2015/04/import-and-use-external-database-in.html)
> 3. [Reading sqlite file from asset folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20857734/reading-sqlite-file-from-asset-folder)
> 4. [Not empty LiteSQL DB at start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7496229/not-empty-litesql-db-at-start/7496308#7496308)
> 5. [Updating prepopulated database in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4189956/updating-prepopulated-database-in-android)
> 6. [Using your own SQLite database in Android applications](https://blog.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/)

**This is my DatabaseHelper.java**

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    // DATABASE NAME
    public static String DATABASE_PATH = "/data/data/com.example.ilhamakbar.yukmasakbygd/databases/";
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "yukmasak.db";
    private final Context myContext;
    private SQLiteOpenHelper openHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase myDatabase;

    int id = 0;
    Random random = new Random();

    //TABLE NAMES
    public static final String EXPERT_TABLE = "expertTable";
    public static final String INGREDIENTS_TABLE = "ingredientsTable";
    public static final String MENU_TABLE = "menuTable";

    // FOUR LINES BELOW ARE CODES FOR EXPERT TABLE'S COLUMNS NAME. SO PLEASE DON'T MESS IT UP
    public static final String COL_EXPERT_CODE = "expertCode";
    public static final String COL_EXPERT_NAME = "expertName";
    public static final String COL_EXPERT_WEIGHTING = "expertWeighting";

    // FOUR LINES BELOW ARE CODES FOR INGREDIENTS TABLE'S COLUMNS NAME. SO PLEASE DON'T MESS IT UP
    public static final String COL_INGREDIENTS_CODE = "ingredientsCode";
    public static final String COL_INGREDIENTS_CODEFK = "ingredientsCodeFK";
    public static final String COL_INGREDIENTS_NAME = "ingredientsName";
    public static final String COL_INGREDIENTS_QTY = "ingredientsQty";

    // FOUR LINES BELOW ARE CODES FOR MENU TABLE'S COLUMNS NAME. SO PLEASE DON'T MESS IT UP
    public static final String COL_MENU_CODE = "menuCode";
    public static final String COL_MENU_NAME = "menuName";
    public static final String COL_MENU_PICTURE = "menuPictures";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
        this.myContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + EXPERT_TABLE + "(expertCode STRING PRIMARY KEY, expertName TEXT, expertWeighting FLOAT)");
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + INGREDIENTS_TABLE + "(ingridientsCode STRING PRIMARY KEY, ingridientsCodeFK STRING, ingredientsName TEXT, ingredientsQty FLOAT, FOREIGN KEY (ingridientsCodeFK) REFERENCES EXPERT_TABLE(expertCode))");
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + MENU_TABLE + "(menuCode STRING PRIMARY KEY, menuName TEXT, menuPictures BLOB)");
        createDB();
    }

    private void createDB(){
        boolean dbExist = dbExists();
        if(!dbExist){
            copyDatabase();
        }
        else if(dbExist){
            copyDatabase();
        }
    }

    private boolean dbExists(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = null;
        try{
            String dbPath = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
            db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(dbPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
            db.setLocale(Locale.getDefault());
            db.setLockingEnabled(true);
            db.setVersion(1);
        }
        catch(SQLiteException e){
            Log.e("SQL Helper", "database not found");
        }
        if(db != null){
            db.close();
        }
        return db != null ? true : false;
    }

    // Additional codes and will be deleted if not working
    public void createDatabase() throws IOException{            
        boolean dbExist = checkDatabase();

        if(dbExist){
            //do nothing - database already exist
        }else{

            //By calling this method and empty database will be created into the default system path
            //of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that database with our database.
            this.getReadableDatabase();

            try{
                copyDatabase();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new Error("Error copying database");
            }
        }

        createDB();
    }

    private boolean checkDatabase(){
        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

        try{
            String myPath = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

        }catch(SQLiteException e){
            //database does't exist yet.
        }

        if(checkDB != null){
            checkDB.close();
        }

        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }

    public void openDB(){
        this.myDatabase = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    public void closeDB(){
        if(myDatabase != null){
            this.myDatabase.close();
        }
    }

    private void copyDatabase(){
        InputStream iStream = null;
        OutputStream oStream = null;

        // Path to the just created empty db
        String outFileName = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;

        try{
            iStream = myContext.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);        // Open your local db as the input stream
            oStream = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);                // Open the empty db as the output stream
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];                             // Transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
            int length;
            while ((length = iStream.read(buffer))>0){
                oStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }

            //Close the streams
            oStream.flush();
            oStream.close();
            iStream.close();
        }
        catch(IOException ioe){
            throw new Error("Problem copying database from resource file.");
        }
    }

    public void openDatabase() throws SQLException {
        //Open the database
        String myPath = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
        myDatabase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {
        if(myDatabase != null)
            myDatabase.close();

        super.close();

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // DROP OLDER TABLES IF EXISTED
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + EXPERT_TABLE);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + INGREDIENTS_TABLE);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + MENU_TABLE);

        onCreate(db);
    }

    public boolean insertExpertTable(String code, String name, String weighting){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL_EXPERT_CODE, code);
        contentValues.put(COL_EXPERT_NAME, name);
        contentValues.put(COL_EXPERT_WEIGHTING, weighting);

        long result = db.insert(EXPERT_TABLE, null, contentValues);
        if(result == -1)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }

    public boolean insertIngredientsTable(String code, String codefk, String name, String qty){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL_INGREDIENTS_CODE, code);
        contentValues.put(COL_INGREDIENTS_CODEFK, codefk);
        contentValues.put(COL_INGREDIENTS_NAME, name);
        contentValues.put(COL_INGREDIENTS_QTY, qty);

        long result = db.insert(INGREDIENTS_TABLE, null, contentValues);
        if(result == -1)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }

    public boolean insertMenuTable(String code, String name, byte[] picture){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL_MENU_CODE, code);
        contentValues.put(COL_MENU_NAME, name);
        contentValues.put("menuPictures", picture);

        long result = db.insert(MENU_TABLE, null, contentValues);
        if(result == -1) {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public Cursor getAllExpertData(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        Cursor res = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + EXPERT_TABLE, null);
        return res;
    }

    public Cursor getAllIngredientsData(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        Cursor res = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + INGREDIENTS_TABLE, null);
        return res;
    }

    public Cursor getAllMenuData(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        Cursor res = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + MENU_TABLE, null);
        return res;
    }

    public List<String> getExpertTableData(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + EXPERT_TABLE, null);

        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            // WHICH COLUMN I WANT TO EXPORT
            list.add(cursor.getString(0)+" | " + cursor.getString(1)+" | " + cursor.getString(2)+"\n" );
        }

        cursor.close();
        return list;
    }

    public List<String> getIngridientsTableData(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + INGREDIENTS_TABLE, null);

        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            // WHICH COLUMN I WANT TO EXPORT
            list.add(cursor.getString(0)+" | " + cursor.getString(1)+" | " + cursor.getString(2)+"\n" );
        }

        cursor.close();
        return list;
    }

    public List<Object> getMenuTableData(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + MENU_TABLE, null);

        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            // WHICH COLUMN I WANT TO EXPORT
            list.add(cursor.getString(0)+" | " + cursor.getString(1)+" | " + cursor.getBlob(2)+"\n" );
        }

        cursor.close();
        return list;
    }

    public boolean updateExpertData(String code, String name, String weighting, String change_code){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL_EXPERT_CODE, code);
        contentValues.put(COL_EXPERT_NAME, name);
        contentValues.put(COL_EXPERT_WEIGHTING, weighting);
        contentValues.put(COL_EXPERT_CODE, change_code);
        db.update(EXPERT_TABLE, contentValues, "expertCode=?",new String[] {change_code});
        return true;
    }

    public boolean updateIngredientsData(String code, String codefk, String name, String qty, String change_code){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL_INGREDIENTS_CODE, code);
        contentValues.put(COL_INGREDIENTS_CODEFK, codefk);
        contentValues.put(COL_INGREDIENTS_NAME, name);
        contentValues.put(COL_INGREDIENTS_QTY, qty);
        contentValues.put(COL_INGREDIENTS_CODE, change_code);
        db.update(INGREDIENTS_TABLE, contentValues, "ingridientsCode=?",new String[] {change_code});
        return true;
    }

//    public boolean updateMenuData(String code, String name, String picture, String change_code){
//        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
//
//        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
//        contentValues.put(COL_MENU_CODE, code);
//        contentValues.put(COL_MENU_NAME, name);
//        contentValues.put(COL_MENU_PICTURE, picture);
//        contentValues.put(COL_MENU_CODE, change_code);
//        db.update(MENU_TABLE, contentValues, "menuCode=?",new String[] {change_code});
//        return true;
//    }

    public Integer deleteExpertData(String change_code){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        return db.delete(EXPERT_TABLE, "expertCode=?", new String[] {change_code});
    }

    public Integer deleteIngredientsData(String change_code){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        return db.delete(INGREDIENTS_TABLE, "ingridientsCode=?", new String[] {change_code});
    }

    public Integer deleteMenuData(String change_code){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        return db.delete(MENU_TABLE, "menuCode=?", new String[] {change_code});
    }
}
```

**This is my TabActivityAdministrator.java**

```
public class TabActivityAdministrator01 extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {
    // THESE CODES BELOW UNTIL THE NEXT @OVERRIDE IS USED TO CALL THE DATABASEHELPER.JAVA
    DatabaseHelper myDb;
    private EditText editExpertWeightingCode,
                     editExpertWeightingName,
                     editExpertWeightingValue,
                     editExpertWeightingChangedCode;
    private Button buttonExpertAddData,
                   buttonExpertViewData,
                   buttonExpertUpdateData,
                   buttonExpertDeleteData;
    private ListView listViewExpertData;

    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static TabActivityAdministrator01 newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        TabActivityAdministrator01 fragment = new TabActivityAdministrator01();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        //args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        //args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        myDb = new DatabaseHelper(getContext());
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab_activity_administrator01,container,false);

        editExpertWeightingCode = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.edtWeightingCode_TabActivityAdministrator01);
        editExpertWeightingName = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.edtWeightingName_TabActivityAdministrator01);
        editExpertWeightingValue = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.edtWeightingValue_TabActivityAdministrator01);
        editExpertWeightingChangedCode = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.edtWeightingChangedCode_TabActivityAdministrator01);
        buttonExpertAddData = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btnExpertAddData_TabActivityAdministrator01);
        buttonExpertViewData = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btnExpertViewData_TabActivityAdministrator01);
        buttonExpertUpdateData = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btnExpertUpdateData_TabActivityAdministrator01);
        buttonExpertDeleteData = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btnExpertDeleteData_TabActivityAdministrator01);
        listViewExpertData = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.lvExpertViewData_TabActivityAdministrator01);

        AddExpertData();
        ViewExpertData();
        UpdateExpertData();
        DeleteExpertData();

        return view;
    }

    // THESE CODES BELOW FOR ADDING EXPERT DATAS TO MY DATABASE
    public void AddExpertData(){
        buttonExpertAddData.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        boolean isInserted = myDb.insertExpertTable(editExpertWeightingCode.getText().toString(),
                                                                    editExpertWeightingName.getText().toString(),
                                                                    editExpertWeightingValue.getText().toString() );

                        if(isInserted = true)
                            Toast.makeText(TabActivityAdministrator01.this.getActivity(), "Data Berhasil Dimasukkan", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        else
                            Toast.makeText(TabActivityAdministrator01.this.getActivity(), "Data Gagal Dimasukkan", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        editExpertWeightingCode.getText().clear();      // clear edit text for expertWeightingCode
                        editExpertWeightingName.getText().clear();      // clear edit text for expertWeightingName
                        editExpertWeightingValue.getText().clear();     // clear edit text for expertWeightingValue
                    }
                }
        );
    }

    /*
    // THESE CODES BELOW FOR VIEWING DATAS ON MY DATABASE WITH POP UP DATAS
    public void ViewExpertData(){
        buttonExpertViewData.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Cursor res = myDb.getAllExpertData();
                        if(res.getCount() == 0){
                            // IF NO DATA WAS FOUND, THIS MESSAGE BELOW WILL APPEAR
                            ShowMessage("Error", "Data Tidak Ditemukan");
                            return;
                        }

                        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                        while(res.moveToNext()){
                            buffer.append("CODE: " +res.getString(0)+"\n");
                            buffer.append("NAMA: " +res.getString(1)+"\n");
                            buffer.append("BOBOT: " +res.getString(2)+"\n\n");
                        }

                        // IF THE DATA WAS FOUND, THIS MESSAGE BELOW WILL APPEAR
                        ShowMessage("Data", buffer.toString());
                    }
                }
        );
    }
    */

    // THESE CODES BELOW FOR VIEWING DATAS ON MY DATABASE WITH POP UP DATAS     // will be deleted if unused
    public void ViewExpertData(){
        buttonExpertViewData.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Cursor res = myDb.getAllExpertData();
                        if(res.getCount() == 0){
                            // IF NO DATA WAS FOUND, THIS MESSAGE BELOW WILL APPEAR
                            ShowMessage("Error", "Data Tidak Ditemukan");
                            return;
                        }
                        while(res.moveToNext()){
                            myDb = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity());
                            List<String> yukmasak = myDb.getExpertTableData();
                            myDb.closeDB();
                            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, yukmasak);
                            listViewExpertData.setAdapter(adapter);
                        }
                    }
                }
        );
    }

    public void ShowMessage(String title, String message){
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this.getActivity());
        builder.setCancelable(true);
        builder.setTitle(title);
        builder.setMessage(message);
        builder.show();
    }

    // THESE CODES BELOW FOR UPDATING DATAS ON MY DATABASE
    public void UpdateExpertData(){
        buttonExpertUpdateData.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        boolean isUpdated = myDb.updateExpertData(editExpertWeightingCode.getText().toString(),
                                                                  editExpertWeightingName.getText().toString(),
                                                                  editExpertWeightingValue.getText().toString(),
                                                                  editExpertWeightingChangedCode.getText().toString());

                        if(isUpdated=true)
                            Toast.makeText(TabActivityAdministrator01.this.getActivity(), "Data Berhasil Diperbaharui", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        else
                            Toast.makeText(TabActivityAdministrator01.this.getActivity(), "Data Gagal Diperbaharui", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        editExpertWeightingCode.getText().clear();               // clear edit text for expertWeightingCode
                        editExpertWeightingName.getText().clear();               // clear edit text for expertWeightingName
                        editExpertWeightingValue.getText().clear();              // clear edit text for expertWeightingValue
                        editExpertWeightingChangedCode.getText().clear();        // clear edit text for expertWeightinChangedgCode
                    }
                }
        );
    }

    // THESE CODES BELOW FOR DELETING DATAS ON MY DATABASE
    public void DeleteExpertData(){
        buttonExpertDeleteData.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        Integer deletedRows = myDb.deleteExpertData(editExpertWeightingChangedCode.getText().toString());
                        if(deletedRows > 0)
                            Toast.makeText(TabActivityAdministrator01.this.getActivity(), "Data Berhasil Dihapus", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        else
                            Toast.makeText(TabActivityAdministrator01.this.getActivity(), "Data Gagal Dihapus", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        editExpertWeightingChangedCode.getText().clear();        // clear edit text for expertWeightinChangedgCode
                    }
                }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any exception? Also don't use hardcoded paths like this "/data/data/com.example.ilhamakbar.yukmasakbygd/databases/". There is no guarantee that this folder will be available. Instead use `context.getDataDir()` or `context.getDatabathPath()`

Comment: There's no any exception shown

Comment: Do you want to create an empty database, or ship an existing database with your app? Because this code tries to do both.

Comment: @CL: I want to ship an existing database with my app when i build an apk

Comment: Then just use [SQLiteAssetHelper](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-sqlite-asset-helper/).

Comment: I had a similar problem before in one of my apps. Did you try moving the `copyDatabase` method to somewhere like the `Application` class? I remember there was a file lock on the db file when `onCreate` was called.

Comment: @CL: I will try first. Thank you for your help

Comment: @Naveen Dissanayake: What do you mean by file lock? Actually when I build an APK and run it on my phone, the databases is not exist. But when I run it on a emulator like Nox App, the database is exist.

Comment: I mean you cannot access the file when `onCreate` is called. I can't be sure why it would work on the emulator though.

Comment: @CL: Why you marked my question as duplicated? I already stated that I followed the instruection from the link above and it doesn't work. You told me to open Ship an application with a database link? Do you open my link number 6? I already wrote it.

Comment: Your code does not do the same thing as in that link. Neither does it use SQLiteAssetHelper.